# Scheduling not working for PM time : Android

Tags: android, schedule

I have made an application, and its working very fine.

One problem I'm having regarding scheduling.
I have a custom scheduler in my app, where I have used date and time picker to pick date/time. If it is a AM time then this is working fine, but if it is PM time then its not working. I spent a big time to resolve it but not getting any idea to resolve it.

**Code to pick date:**

```
DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dateEndSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener()
{   
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int date) 
    {
        mDay = date;
        mMonth = month;
        mYear = year;
    }
};
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), dateEndSetListener, c.get(Calendar.YEAR), c.get(Calendar.MONTH), c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
datePickerDialog.show();
```

**Code to pick time**

```
TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener timeEndSetListener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener()
{
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute)
    {
        mHour = hourOfDay;
        mMinut = minute;
    }
};
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), timeEndSetListener, c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), c.get(Calendar.MINUTE), false);
timePickerDialog.show();
```

**Code for scheduling fake call**

```
AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmManagerForSchedullingCallBrodcastReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
Calendar time = Calendar.getInstance();
time.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, date);
time.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
time.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
time.set(Calendar.HOUR, hour);
time.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minut);
time.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time.getTimeInMillis(), pi);
```

Your help will be very appreciated.. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution for my own question.

I changed **CODE BLOCK A** with **CODE BLOCK B** as given below:

**CODE BLOCK A**

```
Calendar time = Calendar.getInstance();
time.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, date);
time.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
time.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
time.set(Calendar.HOUR, hour);
time.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minut);
time.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time.getTimeInMillis(), pi);
```

**CODE BLOCK B**

```
Calendar time = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault(), Locale.getDefault());
time.set(year, month, date, hour, minut, 0);
am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time.getTimeInMillis(), pi);
```

And its working magically. I'm posting this answer for those guys who is facing the same problem. Thanks

Comment: It's not magic, it works because BLOCK B is using hourOfDay, which works with 24h format, while BLOCK A is using Calendar.HOUR which works with 12h format :)